# Im trying to load and display a table from sql into my datagrid in C# but its not displaying

Tags: c#

```
//instantiating connection          
dbConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = local host; initial catalog=Project; Integrated Security = SSPI ");

ds = new DataSet();
//select everything from the table 

dbCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Shops;", dbConn);
dbAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(dbCommand);
//filling the datagrid

dbAdapter.Fill(ds, "All Shops");
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["All Shops"];
```

Comment: You have to bind data after datasource

Comment: Are you getting any error? What's about opening the connection? 
`dbConn.Open()`

Comment: Do you get the data at all? Can you see it in the debuger?

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView`!! This is wrong and confusing and and bound to get wrong answers wasting everybody's time.. Always call things by their __right__ name! Yes, it takes __four__ letters more to type, but when asking for help here is __not__ the time to be so lazy..! -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show data into datagrid you need to assign datasource and then use `DataBind()` to bind the data.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["All Shops"];
dataGridView1.DataBind(); // use this after assigning the datasource
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void GetResults()
        {
            //Establishing the MySQL Connection
             MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Database=potentiality_live;Data Source=eu;User Id=ptly;Password=phat40");

            string query;
            MySqlCommand SqlCommand;
            MySqlDataReader reader;

            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
//Open the connection to db
            conn.Open();

//Generating the query to fetch the contact details
            query = "SELECT id,date_time,link FROM'sdfsdfsdf'";

 SqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
            adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
//execute the query
            reader = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
//Assign the results 
            GridView1.DataSource = reader;

//Bind the data
            GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

Reference:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/453091/how-to-get-data-from-sql-database-to-gridview-by-c